# displaying NSDate on iphone different on different devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For some reason, when I display a NSDate, it displays as "2010-11-18 18:00:02 -8000". On other devices, it displays as "2010-11-18 18:00:02 GMT" except the time is adjusted to a GMT time. I'm just printing it out as NSLog(@"%@", NSDate);

Any idea about this inconsistency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a NSDateFormatter and perhaps setting the locale (setLocale) if you want consistant output otherwise you leave it up to the OS and there's really no telling when the default display style might change.

Answer (score 0):

It's describing the time using the current locale. If you can convince it you're in a locale that uses GMT, you, too, can have it display the time in GMT without any offset.